# Best practice with dll archives

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

So perhaps this is not the best practice of how to maintain dll's, but currently I am employing a repository of current dll versions, and an archive of older versions. The intent was to simply make it quicker to browse to the current version of a given dll when wishing to add a reference to one of them in any given project.

So when employing one in a project I have "copy local" set to true. However I have just realized that the path remains set at the repository location and that the dll in the project is being automatically replaced with the repo version should it be updated.

A further intent was to manually update to newer dll when appropriate, managed, and could be tested, rather than having potentially breaking changes introduced.

I see now this might be design as potentially in deployment a shared dll of the wrong version may break functionality anyhow. So I am wondering if there is a consensus of thought on how to maintain things or how to proceed?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for nuget packages instead of assembly references. A NuGet source aka repository can be a local or shared folder

Comment: You can set up a nuget server which can help this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is definitely to use a package manager, in C# it's usually [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/).

This [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx) explains how to host and deploy your own server. After that you manage your corporate dlls in the same way you manage external dlls, through nuget.

Comment: Agreed. NuGet supports a file based repository now even, so there's no barrier of entry at all. We also tried the example you linked to, which offers a thin layer on top of that file-based solution, and then the solution that we currently use is native support by our CI (TeamCity) which can just package and host NuGets automatically, which is just really convenient.

Comment: Yes this looks useful for ongoing adoption I hadn't thought about this approach. For this particular project however, as I cant afford it with the current time constraint I thought instead I would simply include the version number in the name. If the version evolves in the repo current folder, it will of course hiccup, but at that point I can re-reference to the newly archived version, if there is a break. Ongoing though Nuget might just work for us, particularly with a folder based approach - cheers guys!

Comment: A slight further hiccup however it seems VS or VB doesnt like underscores or periods in the name - FileNotFoundException when so!

Comment: In fact rather it is renaming the dll that is a problem!